# LiteSpeed/Apache WebSocket Proxy setup

Tags: apache, websocket, server, ratchet, litespeed

I have a server running the LiteSpeed, and I am using the Ratchet to create a Websocket server. After that I follow this instruction  [LiteSpeed Websocket Proxy](https://docs.litespeedtech.com/lsws/cp/cpanel/websocket-proxy/) to setup the proxy

It works, when I only have one port `8080`, but I want to open more than one port, set up more than one server runs.
I tried something like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^websocket$ http://sample:8080/ [P,L]
RewriteRule ^second$ http://sample:8081/ [P,L]
RewriteRule ^third$ http://sample:8082/ [P,L]
ProxyPass / ws://sample:8080/
ProxyPass / ws://sample:8081/
Proxypass / ws://sample:8082/
</IfModule>
```

I have three WebSocket server running in three different port. Does anyone has an idea for taht?

Answer (score 0):

After I try this, it works

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^websocket$ http://sample:8080/ [P,L]
RewriteRule ^second$ http://sample:8081/ [P,L]
RewriteRule ^third$ http://sample:8082/ [P,L]
ProxyPass /ws ws://sample:8080/
ProxyPass /ws2 ws://sample:8081/
Proxypass /ws3 ws://sample:8082/
</IfModule>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).